# Collapsing and expanding dynamically cloned forms

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

**Summary**

I have a form in my HTML. This form is dynamically cloned when the user presses the `#addOne` button. Each form is validated before the user can submit it. My validation method is the jQuery plugin. Each form is unique to a page number. For example, the first form is page 3, the second form is page 2, and the third form is page 1. Each form will submit to its unique page number using Ajax. After the user submits the form successfully, I want that particular form to collapse (hide) and I want the `.expand` div to show. When the user clicks on the `.expand` div, I want that particular form to show again (expand) and I want the `.expand` div to collapse (hide). Here's what I have so far: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgdjndsk/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="article_properties">
                        <form class="article_properties_form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <p style="display: inline">Page Number</p>
                        <div style="background-color: #FF355E; padding: 5px; display: inline; margin-left: 5px">

                        <p style="display: inline" class="pageNumber"></p>
                        </div>
                        <textarea style="display: none" class="inputNumber" name="pageNumber"></textarea>
                        <p>Image</p>
                        <input style="padding: 0px" type="file" name="image">
                            <p>Subtitle</p>
                            <input type="text" name="subtitle">

                            <p>Text</p>
                            <textarea name="text" rows="4"></textarea>
                            <input id="properties_btn" type="submit" value="Submit/Update">
                            <hr style="border: 1px dotted lightgray; margin-bottom: 50px">

                            <div style="display: none" class="expand">
                              <p>
                              Expand Form [Page Number should be here]
                              </p>
                            </div>
                        </form>



                    </div> <!--End of article properties div-->
                <div id="addOne"><p>+Add page</p></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".article_properties_form").validate({
        errorElement: 'div',
        rules: {
            image: {
                required: true,
                extension: "jpg,jpeg,png"
            },

            subtitle: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 25
            },
            text: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 35,
                maxlength: 275
            }
        },

        messages: {
            image: {
                required: "This page needs an image",
                extension: "You're only allowed to upload jpg or png images."
            },

            subtitle: {
                required: "You have to provide a subtitle for this page!",
                minlength: "Your subtitle must be at least 2 characters long",
                maxlength: "Your subtitle must be less than 25 characters long"
            },
            text: {
                required: "Please enter text for this page",
                minlength: "Your text must be at least 35 characters long",
                maxlength: "Your text must be less than 275 characters long"
            },
        },

        });

var numPages = 3;
$('.pageNumber').text(numPages);
$('.inputNumber').text(numPages);

$('#addOne').click(function()
                    {

                        numPages--;

                        if (numPages == 1)
                        {
                            var articlePropsTemplate = $('.article_properties_form:last').clone();           
                                $('.article_properties').append(articlePropsTemplate);                         
                                $('.pageNumber:last').text(numPages);
                                $('.inputNumber:last').text(numPages);
                                 articlePropsTemplate[0].reset();
                                 add_validation_for_forms();

                    articlePropsTemplate.validate().resetForm();
                                $('#addOne').hide();
                        }

                        else
                        {
                                var articlePropsTemplate = $('.article_properties_form:last').clone();
                                $('.article_properties').append(articlePropsTemplate);
                                 articlePropsTemplate[0].reset();
                                $('.pageNumber:last').text(numPages);
                                $('.inputNumber:last').text(numPages);
                                add_validation_for_forms();
                                articlePropsTemplate.validate().resetForm();
                        }

                });

                function add_validation_for_forms(){
                $(".article_properties_form").each(function(){
                    $(this).validate({
                        errorElement: 'div',

        rules: {
            image: {
                required: true,
                extension: "jpg|jpeg|png"
            },

            subtitle: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 25
            },
            text: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 35,
                maxlength: 275
            }
        },

        messages: {
            image: {
                required: "This page needs an image",
                extension: "You're only allowed to upload jpg or png images."
            },

            subtitle: {
                required: "You have to provide a subtitle for this page!",
                minlength: "Your subtitle must be at least 2 characters long",
                maxlength: "Your subtitle must be less than 25 characters long"
            },
            text: {
                required: "Please enter text for this page",
                minlength: "Your text must be at least 35 characters long",
                maxlength: "Your text must be less than 275 characters long"
            },
        },
                    });
               });
              }


$('body').on('submit','.article_properties_form', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();


                    if ($('.article_properties_form').valid())
                    {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '',
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function(data) {
                                $(this).hide();
                            $(".expand").show();
                        }   
                    });
                   }

                   else
                   {

                   }
                })
```

Comment: I don't see a specific question here... nor can we test out the ajax within your jsFiddle to see what might be wrong.  Please edit the question to be more specific about the problem you're having.

Comment: **Hint**:  anything you would need to do with a valid form when the submit button is clicked, like ajax or expand/collapse, would only go inside the plugin's `submitHandler` callback.  Please refer to the docs:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

Comment: I don't understand your `click` function.  You have an if/else where 90% of the code under the `true` condition is identical to what's under the `false` (`else`) condition.  It's pointless to duplicate code on both sides of an if/else since the same code will run whether the `if` is `true` or `false`.  Just put those lines above/outside the if/else

Comment: @Sparky When the user submits a particular form successfully, I want that form to hide and show the .expand div. When the user clicks on the .expand div, that div will hide and that form will reappear...if that makes sense?

Comment: Yes, your stated requirement always made sense.  However, your OP does not contain a question... it's merely a functional specification, with a jsFiddle that's practically useless since we cannot submit a form via ajax.  I attempted to fix the issues I found, but then other issues appeared.  I'm afraid your whole approach needs some work (see my second and third comments).  Please condense the example code down to the minimal required to reproduce the exact issue you're having.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sparky You could remove the Ajax because the Ajax works correctly. I have updated the jsfiddle to show you what happens: https://jsfiddle.net/mLby0es9/  When you submit the form with all required information, the form disappears with the .expand div.

Comment: Since you put `div.expand` within the `form` container, of course it vanishes along with the `form`.  You'll have to move `.expand` to outside of the `form`... that's one issue.

Comment: @Sparky But if I put .expand outside the form, then there won't be a .expand div for each form. I want each form to have it's own unique .expand div, so when the user decides to submit one form, that form will be hidden and the .expand div shown

Comment: **It's impossible to see something inside a hidden container.**  When the `form` is hidden, then everything inside the `form` will be hidden... no exceptions.  Simply clone the `div.expand` separate from the `form`.  I don't understand how you were able to put this all together and successfully get validation working on all dynamic forms, but then unable to fix these relatively minor issues.  Did you get this code from somebody else?

Comment: @Sparky If I clone the div.expand separate from the form, will it work successfully? For example, let's say I submitted form 2, will form 2 be hidden and show the right div.expand that will say "Expand Form 2"? Validating the forms separately was an answer I found from someone else's question.

Comment: Matching up the `div` with its corresponding `form` merely requires proper jQuery selectors.  Notice how your existing code works... there is a `:last` selector.  Study your existing code.  Once you understand what's happening ([see my third comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366286/collapsing-and-expanding-dynamically-cloned-forms?noredirect=1#comment64164951_38366286)), then you'll be able to make the necessary changes.  IMO, this is way too much for a single SO question.... the entire thing needs to be re-worked to remove much redundancy, as one example.

Comment: @Sparky Let me try that, and I'll get back with you if I have a specific problem

Comment: @Sparky I've made it work to the point where when the user submits one of the forms, the correct .expand div shows, but I can't seem to hide that form that's being submitted. I've tried $(".article_properties_form:last").hide(); but it's hiding all the forms. Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4yvdxt3w/

Comment: You'll need to target the specific `div` using a combination of jQuery selectors and traversal methods.  See:  https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: @Sparky So far I've managed to hide the current form, but let's say I click the #addOne button and there are two forms on the page. If I submit form 1, form 1 will display the expand div and form 2 will display the expand div as well. How do I make it so that form 2 doesn't display the expand div and only the submitted form displays it? Here's what I have so far https://jsfiddle.net/v8103uh0/

Comment: How?  Again, see my previous comment.  Also, why do you have all that redundant code within the if/else?  It's pointless:  https://jsfiddle.net/v8103uh0/1/

Comment: I see you also ignored [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366286/collapsing-and-expanding-dynamically-cloned-forms?noredirect=1#comment64164132_38366286).  If you put that code within the `submitHandler` you can leverage the `form` argument to traverse over to the specific `div.expand`.  Something *like* `$(form).next('.expand').show()`.

Comment: @Sparky So if I do $(".article_properties_form").validate({submitHandler:function(form) {    
  }
}); This will replace the need for my last block of code for the submitting of the forms?

Comment: Yes, if you add the `submitHandler` option to `.validate()`, then you can remove your `on.submit` handler.

Comment: @Sparky I'm trying to make it so that the form does not refresh. I'm using e.preventDefault(), but the form still refreshes for some reason

Comment: If you use the `submitHandler`, then `e.preventDefault()` is not needed, and will break your code because `e` is not defined.  Pay attention to the error console.